# IntBuffer, ByteBuffer, ByteOrder and GLES20 for Android

Tags: java, android

I have three fragments of code which should behave alike, or maybe not, I'm still studying how OpenGL ES is bound to Java for Android. However I really would like to know why fragment  B and C are behaving differently:

The following (A) works:

```
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        IntBuffer ib = bb.asIntBuffer();
        Log.d("Info", "Generating buffers...");
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(2, ib);
        Log.d("Info", "Done!");
        int buff1 = ib.get();
        int buff2 = ib.get();
        Log.d("A) buff1", String.format("%d", buff1));
        Log.d("A) buff2", String.format("%d", buff2));
```

The following (B) DOES NOT work, and causes SIGSEGV on glGenBuffers; note that the only difference with the previous is in the allocate call instead of allocateDirect:

```
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        IntBuffer ib = bb.asIntBuffer();
        Log.d("Info", "Generating buffers...");
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(2, ib);
        Log.d("Info", "Done!");
        int buff1 = ib.get();
        int buff2 = ib.get();
        Log.d("B) buff1", String.format("%d", buff1));
        Log.d("B) buff2", String.format("%d", buff2));
```

The following (C) works, which really surprised me because it is again a call to allocate and not to allocateDirect:

```
        IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(2);
        Log.d("Info", "Generating buffers...");
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(2, ib);
        Log.d("Info", "Done!");
        int buff1 = ib.get();
        int buff2 = ib.get();
        Log.d("C) buff1", String.format("%d", buff1));
        Log.d("C) buff2", String.format("%d", buff2));
```

With the word "works" I mean that there are no errors showing up in the log and buff1 and buff2 get positive "reasonable" values, like 70001, 140002, or 210004, which look like they may be names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be at [JOGL Javadoc page](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/), in the documentation for interface GL, method:

```
void glGenBuffers(int n, IntBuffer buffers)
```

Here is says that buffers should be a *direct* **OR** *array-backed* IntBuffer, and the buffer created in (B) was neither of these, while (A) was direct but it was not backed, and (C) was not direct but it was backed.

Now I would like to know wether there is an official Google documentation for their binding of OpenGL to the Dalvik system, or shall I assume that it is exactly JOGL? It shouldn't be the same, because interface names are different (for instance JOGL's GLES2 versus Android GLES20).